# Permission Denied when using os.system on Mac

Tags: python, pdf

I am trying to open a pdf reader with a newly generated pdf. On my Windows desktop it works perfectly with the following code, but not on my Mac where is raises "sh: {path} permission denied".

```
path = os.getcwd() + "\{}.pdf".format(tree_name)
os.system(path)
```

I tried using just the name of the pdf file since I want the program to look locally anyways, but that doesn't work either. I need it to work on my Mac laptop absolutely because the code is a for a demo so any help is appreciated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Use the `open` tool](https://ss64.com/osx/open.html) on macOS. (The Windows equivalent is [`start`](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html).)

```
import os
import shlex

path = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), f'{tree_name}.pdf')
os.system(f'open {shlex.quote(path)}')
```

I'm also using `shlex.quote` here to avoid shell injection vulnerabilities, and `os.path.join()` for proper cross-platform path handling.